# Can I factor a cubic polynomial to $(a+bx)(c+dx^2)$

Tags: polynomials

Is there a formula to turn any cubic polynomial into the form $fx^3+gx^2+hx+m=(a+bx)(c+dx^2)$ where all factors in the polynomial can be any number, real or non-real? (The reason I say non-real is I do not want to restrict the factors to complex or split complex numbers)

Comment: Try this with $x(x+2)(x+6)$. Since the prime factor decomposition is unique (up to units and order of factors) one of the factors is known, and the other two do not have opposite roots... But one can linearly change variables like $x+1=t$ to get $x(x+2)=(t-1)(t+1)$, so one factor gets the wanted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, there will be 3rd degree polynomials that can be so constructed.  To create such a polynomial, simply construct a 3rd degree polynomial as the product of the following two factors:

$$(x + 1) \times (x^2 + 1). \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the *constructed* 3rd degree polynomial will, by definition, be factorable into $(x + 1) \times (x^2 + 1)$, so it is clearly possible to construct such a **satisfying 3rd degree polynomial**.

The answer to the general question is **no**, not all 3rd degree polynomials will have such a satisfying factorization.  The following example will illustrate the generic method of construction that may be followed to construct an **unsatisfying** 3rd degree polynomial.

Construct

$$f(x) = (x + 1) \times (x + 2) \times (x + 3) = x^3 + 6x^2 + 11x + 6. \tag2 $$

Assume that $f(x)$ can be factored into

$$g(x) = (a + bx) \times (c + dx^2). \tag3 $$

This implies that any value $(x)$ will satisfy the equation $f(x) = 0$ if and only if the value $(x)$ satisfies the equation $g(x) = 0.$

However, $f(x)$ was constructed so that the only roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$ are the elements in $\{-1, -2, -3\}.$

So, the equation $g(x) = 0$ must have the exact same three roots, $\{-1, -2, -3\}$.  This implies that one of these three roots must be a root of the equation $(a + bx) = 0$, and the other two roots, from $\{-1, -2, -3\}$ must be the roots of the equation $(c + dx^2) = 0.$

However, this is impossible because: 
if you take any two of the three factors, $(x+1), (x + 2), (x+3)$ and multiply them together, you will get a 2nd degree polynomial, where the coefficient of the $(x)^1$ term **is not equal to zero**.

So, the above illustration shows the generic procedure that may be used to construct a 3rd degree polynomial that must be an **unsatisfactory** polynomial (i.e. that does not allow any satisfying factorization).

Answer (score 5):

No. The RHS has factor $(c+dx^2)$ so has roots $\pm\sqrt{\frac{-c}d}$. In other words, it has two roots (whether real or complex) that differ only in their sign. The general cubic on the LHS does not necessarily have such a pair of roots.

Answer (score 1):

Use identity definition, it turned out that you always factor a cubic when: 
m * f = g * h 
Maybe I am wrong, please sympathy with me

Comment: This is correct. $fx^3+gx^2+hx+m = (g/f+x)(h+fx^2)$ when $m=gh/f$. There is a free choice of scalar factor where you can multiply $(g/f+x)$ by any non-zero $b$ as long as you divide $(h+fx^2)$ by $b$ to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as above pointed out RHS have roots as $\alpha$ ,-$ \alpha$ and $\beta$ now for this to be true for LHS roots as well then obviously it has to be a special case. It could be written but with some conditions on coefficients. In general you cannot factorise every cubic polynomial into factors like these.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. I also considered writing it as $a+bx+cy+dxy=(f+gx)(h+ky)$ where $y=x^2$, but I assume that would also not allow a solution for all numbers.